# Azure ML - Train a model on segments of the data-set

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I could really use some help!

The company I work for is made up of 52 very different businesses so I can't predict at the company level but instead need to predict business by business then roll up the result to give company wide prediction.

I have written an ML model in studio.azureml.net
It works great with a 0.947 Coefficient of Determination, but this is for 1 of the businesses.
I now need to train the model for the other 51.

Is there a way to do this in a single ML model rather than having to create 52 very similar models?

Any help would be much appreciated !!!

Kind Regards
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ensembles, combining several models to improve predictions. The most direct is stacking when the outputs of all the models are trained on the entire dataset. 
The method that, I think, corresponds the best to your problem is bagging (bootstrap aggregation). You need to divide the training set into different subsets (each corresponding to a certain business), then train a different model on each subset and combine the result of each classifier. 
Another way is boosting but it is difficult to implement in Azure ML. 
You can see an example in [Azure ML Gallery](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/b6b09fc0c26047e6b4c733ab78a86498).

Quote from book:

> Stacking and bagging can be easily implemented in Azure Machine
>   Learning, but other ensemble methods are more difficult. Also, it
>   turns out to be very tedious to implement in Azure Machine Learning an
>   ensemble of, say, more than five models. The experiment is filled with
>   modules and is quite difficult to maintain. Sometimes it is worthwhile
>   to use any ensemble method available in R or Python. Adding more
>   models to an ensemble written in a script can be as trivial as
>   changing a number in the code, instead of copying and pasting modules
>   into the experiment.

You may also have a look at [sklearn (Python)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) and caret (R) documentation for further details.